# PHP array problem, array_merge() does not solve the problem

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

How to solve array problem?

**Excepted result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/03/13
    [1] => 2011/03/14
    [2] => 2011/02/21
)
```

Failed result that I get now:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/03/13
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/03/14
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/02/21
)
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
function get_dir_iterative($dir='.',$exclude=array('cgi-bin','.','..')){
    $exclude=array_flip($exclude);
    if(!is_dir($dir)){return;}
    $dh=opendir($dir);
    if(!$dh){return;}
    $stack=array($dh);
    $level=0;
    while(count($stack)){
        if(false!==($file=readdir($stack[0]))){
            if(!isset($exclude[$file])){
                if(is_dir("$dir/$file")){
                    $dh=opendir("$file/$dir");
                    if($dh){
                        $d=$file;
                        array_unshift($stack,$dh);
                        ++$level;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isset($d)&&$level>0){
                        $mod=date('Y/m/d',filemtime("$d/$file"));
                        $ds="$d/";
                    }else{
                        $mod=date('Y/m/d',filemtime($file));
                        $ds='';
                    }
                    $array=array($mod);
                    //$b=array_merge($array); // it doesn't solve the problem
                    print_r($array);
                }
            }
        }else{
            closedir(array_shift($stack));
            --$level;
        }
    }
}
get_dir_iterative();
?>
```

**Update:**
On replacing `$array=array($mod);` with `$array[]=$mod;` does not return **excepted result**.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/03/13
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/03/13
    [1] => 2011/03/14
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/03/13
    [1] => 2011/03/14
    [2] => 2011/02/21
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                $array=array($mod);
                //$b=array_merge($array); // it doesn't solve the problem
                print_r($array);
```

For one, array_merge requires at least two arrays to do its thing. You're only providing one, so there's nothing to merge with. Your "live" version creates a new array each time, so that's why you're getting the 'bad' output. Why not simply do

```
 $array[] = $mod;
```

which'll append the file's mtime to the array on each iteration? You might want to store the file's details as well, so you know where the mtime's coming from, so

```
 $array[$dir/$file] = $mod;
```

might be of more use.

Comment: You're doing the print_r from within the loop, so you're getting all the intermediate stages while the array's still being built. Move the print_r() command OUTSIDE the while() loop so you only get the final result.

Answer (score 3):

array_merge() takes several parameters, the arrays that you want to merge, in your situation it should be:

```
array_merge($array, $mod);
// Or:
$array[] = $mod;
```

Note that you can simply add a new entry to your global array (second example) to add a value. Array_merge eats more memory than it needs.

Comment: Unfortunately `$array[]=$mod;` returns `Array ( [0] => 2011/03/13 ) Array ( [0] => 2011/03/13 [1] => 2011/03/14 ) Array ( [0] => 2011/03/13 [1] => 2011/03/14 [2] => 2011/02/21 )` **and not** `Array ( [0] => 2011/03/13 [1] => 2011/03/14 [2] => 2011/02/21 )`. Any solution?

Comment: Well, why don't you print your value after the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by replacing this code: `$array=array($mod);` with this code: `$array[]=$mod;`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the commented out line with `$b[] = $array`

Comment: You're doing a print_r from within the loop, so you're seeing the array at each iteration as it's built. move the print_r statement OUTSIDE the loop so you only see the final result. I don't know why you're getting the full y/m/d h:m:s output - your date format string should only return the y/m/d portion. Possibly your live code is doing something different than what you'd pasted here.